# Exception handling in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

Our product is going to live soon, and some of the users are testing on it. Sometimes, they got the exception randomly and currently, the only way for me to know about it is `ssh` to the server and scan thousand lines of log in order to know the exception.

In my 8 hours working stack (Java, Spring, ...), I can configure the exception through Aspect, Interceptor in order to watch the exception and notify about the exception through email (sending log file, exception reason to me).

How can I do that in Meteor ? What is the error handling strategy ? Is there any thing that close to Interceptor/Aspect in Meteor so I can inject the email sending during the exception ? I don't really want to use any external service to watch our app for the performance / exception

Answer (score 1):

Some packages look promising. Winston with the [email transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#mail-transport) kinda suit my needs. I will update this answer if I come up successfully with that

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Email alerts for exception handling.
Add package called email using meteor add email

use callback method

```
      Meteor.call('methodname', function (err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    //perform some action
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                    Meteor.call('sendEmail',"error in this method");
                   //here sendEmail methods send email about the error 
                }
            });
```

Comment: nope. i will have to change all the funtions in order to catch the exception, which is not the purpose of exception notifications. please read all my question to understand the scenario